# loading images from /images not working in production | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails app was loading images I added previously. The old ones are all loading from /assets (and actually loading) the new images I add are trying to load from /images instead of /assets (and not working)

My rails app is running on Ubuntu 16 with Nginx and passenger.

The way I get them is just by entering the name of the file with .png at the end (ex: picture.png) into a simple_form string input.

And it is rendered from this: `<%= image_tag("#{post.thumbnail_link}", :alt => "#{post.title}", :width => 320, :height => 180, class: "news-object") %>`

And through this on the post show: `<%= image_tag("#{@post.thumbnail_link}", :alt => "#{@post.title}", class: "inpost-thumb") %>`

The ones added previously also load with a long string of seemingly random numbers/letters. - The new ones don't.

The only thing I can think that is different is that the new images have been pushed to the server recently, whereas the old images may have been there when I put the rails app onto a production server.

I've tried doing `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["*.png"]` in `config/initializers/assets` but that doesn't work.

The images are loading fine in development on localhost.

> I want the images to load from `/assets` like the old ones do.
>   Both old and new are in `/assets/images`

Comment: Are you on Heroku, by chance?

Comment: @NMPennypacker No, I'm using a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16 droplet.

Comment: Try this on your machine: Run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clobber` and then `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Add and commit the changes and run a deploy

Comment: @NMPennypacker Thank you! I actually just ran this straight through my ubuntu server instead. I guess it just clobbered it until it worked, lol. Please, answer this question so I can reward you for your help.

Comment: Cool. I added an answer. If you do that on your machine you probably don't have to set the `RAILS_ENV`. If it worked in production, you should still precompile locally and commit the changes to version control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try running:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clobber`

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Add and commit the changes and run a deploy. Looks like your new assets simply haven't been compiled.

More info on the Rails asset pipeline can be found here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

A quick read through there may save you quite a bit of time.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to run this every time I add new assets to my rails app?

Comment: Yes, every time you add/change anything in `/assets`. Some people choose to automate it in a build process.